# newVal of a watcher does not change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

as shown in the following `stackbiltz` link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-2a8a7r?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FGUIEpochAgo.vue)

i have `input` and i want to set the value that to be displayed in the `input` to, for example, to 4 whenever the user attempted to enter values lower than 4
it seems ridiculous but when i run the code, initially, if i entered a value lower than 4, then the value to be displayed in the `input` is 4. this scenario is ok. but if i attempted for the second time to enter another value lower than 4, then the contents or
the value in the `input` never changes

can you please tell me how to achieve that?

**scenario**

```
1st input: for input = 1 => it will change to 4..tha is oK
2nd input: for input = 3 => it will not change to 4...this is not ok because as long as the input is lower than 4, 4 must be displayed in the input box
```

**note**:

```
i know that if the user successviley attempted to enter values lower than 4, the `input` witll display or will change automatically to be set to 4 for the first attempt only, and for the further attempts the value in the `input` will not change to 4 despite
the user enters values lower than 4 because the `newVal` of the `watcher` does not change. but i do not know how to overcome this problem
```

**update:13.11.2023**:

as shown in the below posted code, `this.§forceUpdate` is used as recommended by one of the memebers in SO community.
i would like to know if there is any other possible solution to sovle this question without resorting to `this.§forceUpdate`?

**code:GUIEpochAgo.vue**

```
<template>
    days ago:
    <input
        type="input"
        :value="compPropsVModelInputDaysAgo"
        @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelInputDaysAgo', $event.target.value)"
        :disabled="isInputDaysAgoDisabled"
        @change="onInputDaysAgoChanged($event.target.value)"
    />
</template>

<script>

let debugTag = 'D.GUIEpochAgo.vue::';
let infoTag = 'I.GUIEpochAgo.vue::';
let verboseTag = 'V.GUIEpochAgo.vue::';
let warnTag = 'W.GUIEpochAgo.vue::';
let errorTag = 'E.GUIEpochAgo.vue::';
let WTFTag = 'WTF.GUIEpochAgo.vue::';
//
export default {
name: 'GUIEpochAgo',
data() {
    return {
    };
},
components: {},
props: {
    vModelInputDaysAgo: {
        type: null,
    },
    isInputDaysAgoDisabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
},
emits: ['vModelInputDaysAgo'],
computed: {
    compPropsVModelInputDaysAgo: {
        get() {
            console.log('get.compPropsVModelInputDaysAgo:', this.vModelInputDaysAgo);
            return this.vModelInputDaysAgo;
        },
        set(value) {
            console.log('set.compPropsVModelInputDaysAgo:', value);
            this.$emit('update:vModelInputDaysAgo', value);
        },
    },
},
methods: {
    onInputDaysAgoChanged(evt) {
        const msg = JSON.stringify({ msg: verboseTag + 'onInputDaysAgoChanged():', evt:evt, typeOfevt:typeof evt });
        console.log(msg);
        if (parseInt(evt) < 4) {
            evt = '4';
        }
        this.compPropsVModelInputDaysAgo = evt;
        this.$forceUpdate()
    },
},
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**code:App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <div class="hello">
     <GUIEpochAgo
        v-model:vModelInputDaysAgo="vModelInputDaysAgo"
    ></GUIEpochAgo>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import GUIEpochAgo from './components/GUIEpochAgo.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      vModelInputDaysAgo: null,
    };
  },
  components: {
    GUIEpochAgo
  },
  watch: {
    vModelInputDaysAgo(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (isFinite(newVal)) {
          const newValAsFloat = parseFloat(newVal);
          if (newValAsFloat < 4) {
              this.vModelInputDaysAgo = '4';
          } else {
              this.vModelInputDaysAgo = newVal;
          }
      } else {
          this.vModelInputDaysAgo = 4;
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, saw a familiar username in question list. Users don't receive notifications from a question they didn't participate in.

Comment: Please, add relevant code to the question, it needs to be understandable without navigating to external link that may become unavailable. The demo seems to work as expected, I see no difference between the first and second input, the value is changed each time the model is updated, i.e. a user moves outside the input. Can you clarify? Browser version and screen recording could help

Comment: @EstusFlask would you please have a look at `scenario` section added tot he question, it might be more discriptive

Comment: It works this way, which seems to be the intended behaviour. https://imgur.com/a/Idbsj45 . Is it different on your side?

Comment: @EstusFlask would you please tell me how did you solved it, i solved it be using `$forceUpsate()` did you use it as well please?

Comment: I used the demo you provided, which contains forceUpdate. It looks like a hack indeed. If the goal is to avoid it then the question needs to reflect it. Please, update it with code

Comment: @EstusFlask do you think that there has been a way to solve it without resorting to the usage of `$forceUpdate' please?!

Comment: Yes, there is a way

Comment: @EstusFlask would you please tell me what is it?

Comment: I'll post an answer. Please, update the question with code and relevant details regarding forceUpdate as suggested, this is required by SO rules because this may help future readers who have the same problem. Otherwise the question suddenly stop making sense if demo link becomes unavailable, this happens very often

Comment: @EstusFlask morning, please find the `update` section added to the question. is it ok?

Comment: Hi, it looks fine

Comment: @EstusFlask morning, yesterday I tried to pass data from a child to parent using store, but the data has not been arrived to the parent. Does that mean, that store can’t transfer data from a child to parent please?

Comment: Hi, do you mean global store, vuex/pinia? No, that's the case for a store. Means there's race condition or a problem with reactivity

Comment: @EstusFlask do you that a store can be used to pass data from a child to parent?

Comment: Yes, it can, the problem is specific to the way it's implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-way binding works in an optimized way that the question shows, it doesn't cover the case when a changed value is provided through a prop at the same tick when it was emitted. The debugging would show that input element receives a new prop but isn't updated because it wasn't marked as changed by the renderer.

It's reasonable for a component to be responsible for its own validation, so the value can be limited inside input component. This requires it to have internal state that is synchronized with parent state:

```
<input
    type="input"
    v-model="value"
    :disabled="isInputDaysAgoDisabled"
/>

...

  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newVal) {
        this.compPropsVModelInputDaysAgo = this.value = Math.max(parseInt(newVal) || 0, 4);
      }
    },
    compPropsVModelInputDaysAgo: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newVal) {
        this.value = Math.max(parseInt(newVal) || 0, 4);
      }
    },    
  }
```

That two watchers depend on each other requires to cover all cases that may lead to a recursion, like inconsistent `'4'` string and `4` digit values.

Comment: would you please differentiate which parts of the code you posted belong to child-comp and which belongs to parent-comp?sorry for inconvenience and thanks in advance

Comment: All the code is for a child. In a parent it's just <GUIEpochAgo v-model:vModelInputDaysAgo="vModelInputDaysAgo">